# Problemas con URL en Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-urls

Tengo una aplicación en Django que en el servidor de prueba corre perfectamente, pero a la hora de hacer el despliegue con el `Mod_WSGI` me da el siguiente error :

```
http://localhost/ingresar?next=/Terry/
```

The requested URL /ingresar was not found on this server.

Estas son mis `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()
import xadmin
xadmin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$','principal.views.inicio'),
    url(r'^usuarios/$','principal.views.usuarios'),
    url(r'^sobre/$','principal.views.sobre'),
    url(r'^evento/$','principal.views.lista_eventos'),
    url(r'^nuevo/$','principal.views.nuevoevento'),
    url(r'^temporadas/$','principal.views.temporadas'),
    url(r'^autores/$','principal.views.autores'),
    url(r'^buscar/$','principal.views.buscarEvento'),
    url(r'^artistas/$','principal.views.artistas'),
    url(r'^addevento/$','principal.views.nuevoevento'),
    url(r'^perfil_eventos/(?P<id_evento>\d+)$','principal.views.detalle_evento'),
    url(r'^perfil_temporadas/(?P<id_temporada>\d+)$','principal.views.detalle_temporada'),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^back/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}
    ),
    url(r'^contacto/$','principal.views.contacto'),
    url(r'^receta/nueva/$','principal.views.nuevoevento'),

    url(r'^usuario/nuevo$','principal.views.nuevo_usuario'),
    url(r'^ingresar/$','principal.views.ingresar'),
    url(r'^privado/$','principal.views.privado'),
    url(r'^cerrar/$', 'principal.views.cerrar'),

)
```

Comment: Si estas sirviendo en el puerto 80?

Comment: @GermanAlzate si hermano uso el puerto 80

Comment: el "/$" si no recuerdo mal tiene el significado de hacer coincidir el final de la expresión regular, prueba el regex y dejarlo sin el $ url(r'^ingresar','principal.views.ingresar'),

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en tu ruta estas fijando el caracter '/' al final, como es una expresión regular django espera que la ruta coincida completamente con la expresión. Pero en la ruta estas colocando **ingresar** sin el slash al final. cambia la expresión regular a:

**'^ingresar'** simplemente o **'^ingresar/?'** donde el símbolo '?' indica que el caracter precedente puede o no existir en la cadena evaluada.